# Headers on a DataTables table collapses until a redraw of some sort occurs. Is there a way to force the headers to be redrawn or something similar?

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

My table is being initialized in this way:

```
distributorsDistributionAreasTable = $('#id').DataTable({
        pageLength: 10,
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        scrollY: '160px',
        scrollCollapse: true,
        searching: true,
    });
```

The table is in a modal dialog. When the dialog loads, the columns collapse to the left. But if I resize the window or click a column, they fix themselves. See the gif. Any ideas what's going on here or how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a responsiveness issue with DataTables.

I would recommend the following to resolve the issue:

1.) Add these scripts/stylesheets into your HTML

```
<script src ="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
```

After you have linked those, in your table initialization, add the following: `responsive: true,` anywhere above your `scrollY` option.

Per the DataTables site, If you are using vertical scrolling (scrollY) and not horizontal scrolling (scrollX), enable the horizontal scrolling option so the table has space to scroll into. `scrollX: true,`

After you enable the scrollX option, add the following to your CSS stylesheet:

```
table.dataTable tbody th,
table.dataTable tbody td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If that doesn't completely solve the issue, after the table is drawn, you can call this to readjust the column(header) sizes.

```
table.columns.adjust().draw();
    });
```

All in all, it should look something like this:

```
distributorsDistributionAreasTable = $('#id').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        pageLength: 10,
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        scrollY: '160px',
        scrollX: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        scroller: true,
        searching: true,
    });
distributorsDistributionAreasTable.columns.adjust().draw();
    });
```

```
table.dataTable tbody th,
table.dataTable tbody td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```